# UIViewControllers... Memory Management With SubViews

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, memory, uiviewcontroller

I have `UIViewController` who has several subviews but tracking each and every subview allocated is difficult task as the actually coder is not me and need to handle the memory consumption.

My question is there a way to control the memory calling a recursive function to remove and release all the subViews in the `UIViewController` without knowing the actual reference name ?

As in the code below  :

```
for (UIView* subview in view){  
    [subview removeFromSuperView];  
    [subview release] ;
    subview = nil;   
}
```

Comment: What's wrong with the code snippet you posted?

Answer (score 2):

When you call `removeFromSuperview` on a view it will automatically decrement the retain count (because the superview no longer requires a reference to the view you've just removed).

If you have added your views to the superview in a standard manner there shouldn't be any need to do what you're doing - either you've added your views and then released them, or your views are properties and the release happens later.

The code you're proposing (the recursive loop on all subviews) is a *bad idea*, because you don't actually know whether your subview is safe to be released or not. You could easily trigger a bad access.

Comment: to add to @lxt, `removeFromSuperview` will decrement the retain count, but will not guarantee that it will become zero. When your `MainView` (from where you are calling the above loop) will be released, it will release it's childs (which the view had retained); the for loop is not needed.

Comment: Can you share some links for removeFromSuperView

Comment: Is there a way where we can release the unused View's when we receive a memory warning??

Comment: Can you share some links for removeFromSuperView and also is there some way to release memory when Memory Warnings are received. as in anyway a by which we can release unused View....  from the purged / Cache data